# Code duplication (or not) - JAVA

Tags: java, interface, instanceof, code-duplication

I have a situation of code duplication (or is it ? ) and I don't know how to avoid it , but still keep clarity in my code.

Let me hugely oversimplify the situation:

```java
// let's say I have a interface Entity

interface Entity {

    public Entity add (Entity operand);

}

// And two classes that implement this interface

class MyInteger implements Entity {

    private int value;

    public Entity add (Entity operand)
    {
         // here I have to manage the situation distinctly if operand is a MyInteger or MyString

    }

}

class MyString implements Entity {

    private String value;

    public Entity add (Entity operand )
    {

    }
}
```

Now, my problem is that the method add in MyString is bassicly the same as the method add in MyInteger. Keep in mind that I have way more types than the two mentioned here, and for some the method add is not the same.

Is this code duplication? And if so, is there a way to avoid it? Cause I can't seem to think of one.

Also , in the add method, how can I switch between the various types operand can have without using if (instanceof ) statements?

Answer (score 1):

Look up the Template pattern. You could refactor and add an Abstract class for any duplicate code. If this is specific to two classes you could have just those two classes extend the Abstract class.

To avoid `instanceof` I'm not sure what would be best but you could chain an extra method specific to an entity class which then calls the super/abstract class if necessary.

Lastly, investigate what possibilities are offered by generics.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or [double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) mechanism.

Your `add(Entity operand)` method has to decide what to do based on the operand passed, and so you can achive this by calling *back* on the operand. e.g.

```
// in MyInteger
public Entity add(Entity operand) {
   operand.addInteger(this);
}

// in MyString
public Entity add(Entity operand) {
   operand.addString(this);
}
```

Note that the implementation of the above changes upon the type called. By redirecting back to the operand your call path is determined by the entity originally called upon *and* the operand used.

Each Entity would have to implement `addInteger(MyInteger p)`, `addString(MyString p)` etc. but at this stage you have concrete types to work with and can determine trivially what to do.

Note that you're not having to use `instanceof` or similar. The above is typesafe and complete. e.g. adding a new operand type will result in an obvious set of refactorings.

Comment: That's a neat way of doing a callback. It's not clear to me how this replaces ´instanceof´ though. Correct me if I'm wrong but the idea here would be to let an entity type handle specifics ?

Comment: If you add MyDouble then that will call addDouble upon the operant. Each operant would have to decide how to add a double to itself (not unreasonably)

Comment: I do not think this does help. Entity is an interface and therefore you cannot call addInteger/addString as a method until it is implemented in Entity. As the other answers said it, you need either an abstract superclass or utility methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's been most helpful.

Comment: I don't get it either.  It means Entity has to know about all possible 'subclasses' into the future and have an addCat(), addDog() method etc..

Answer (score 1):

You could use an abstract class and provide it with the concrete add method.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. There is no concrete add method. The result is different depending on the operands. Say I add two MyIntegers my result is also a MyInteger, but if I add a MyInteger to a MyString the result is a MyString. Could you give me a code example of what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

So far I do not see problems in your approach.

As entity is an instance, you can solve code duplication by:

- Simply ignoring it and do duplication because it will give you a clean solution.
  If you have only a few cases where such duplication occur, it may be better to
  implement it in this way.
- As already said, implement an abstract class e.g. AbstractEntity implementing all
  methods once as protected member methods and declare MyInteger and MyString as subclasses.
- Go further with subclassing, think over what methods are needed for which entity and
  build up a tree of subclasses. Caution: This will hamper further adjustments if you
  cannot do careful design.
- Use an utility class: class with public static methods and a private constructor to
  implement the functionality to need.

How to find out the type of entity:

- Use instanceof (ok, it IS ugly)
- Implement methods in the interface returning the type as Enum or test
  for properties: getType() == STRING or isString()
- Implement methods in the interface doing what you wish: checkIfStringAndAddIt().